# Perform the same operation on multiple JSON fields using JQ

Tags: json, functional-programming, jq

I'm trying to change the values of multiple fields in a JSON object using JQ. However, I want to perform the same operation on each of these fields. I accomplished this, but the way I did seems redundant.

`jq '.fieldOne |= . * 3 | .fieldTwo |= . * 3 | ...'`

Is there a way of doing something along the lines of this: (not exactly this because JQ won't work like that)

`jq '(.fieldOne | .fieldTwo | ...) |= . * 3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the magic of jq, you could just write:

```
(.fieldOne, .fieldTwo) |= .*3
```

More generically, here are two other approaches.

### multiop/2

```
# If the input is an object, $fields should be an array of key names
# If the input is an array, $fields should be an array of integers
def multiop($fields; f):
  if $fields|length == 0 then .
  else .[$fields[0]] |= f
  | multiop($fields[1:]; f)
  end;

multiop(["fieldOne", "fieldTwo"]; . * 3)
```

Or, if you want the operation applied to all fields:

```
multiop( keys_unsorted; .*3)
```

### triple/1

```
def triple(f): f |= . * 3;

triple(.fieldOne, .fieldTwo)
```

Comment: Ah clever, I'm still trying to find a way with pure JQ, but this is helpful thanks

Comment: Thanks! The first line does exactly what I want. I knew there was some syntax I was missing.